# Explicit POST in JSP page

Tags: ajax, jsp

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" action="some.jsp">
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="first" VALUE="First">
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="second" VALUE="Second">

    </FORM>
```

When the form is submitted in the background a POST method is sent to that jsp page with the parameters.

What I am trying to do is that I have an ajax call to a local mediator jsp page which should then take those parameters and post to a page on another domain (this is for me to circumvent the cross-domain problem with ajax calls in IE8).

How would I do an explicit post? Something that takes a URL and the parameters?

Comment: I don't get it - what is the issue at hand here - how to change where the AJAX call posts to or how to redirect the request once on the interim jsp?

Comment: Once on the interim jsp, how to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are having issue with is posting the form, it is as simple as

```
document.forms['form1'].submit()
```

EDIT: In that case, see [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) for how to make a POST or GET request. I would recommend using `request.getParameterMap()` and iterating over that, dropping those parameters into the new outbound request.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.html

Comment: that is javascript, right? Once I am in interim jsp, how do I redirect it basically?